# Tooltip not displaying on fontawesome icon button

Tags: html, css, tooltip, font-awesome

I have a fontawesome icon nested inside a  but the tooltip is not popping up.

```
<i class="fa fa-random" title="some tooltip"></i>
```

style:

```
i.fa {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using a tooltip plugin that uses the `::before` pseudo element then it conflicts with `fontawesome` because it also uses the pesudo element to display the icon.

It is best to wrap your icon inside another tag that gets the tooltip class:

```
<span class="tooltip" title="hello world"><i class="fa fa-random"></i></span>
```